# context-sensitive phpinfo() with specification of a path

Tags: php, directory

I wrote a parser in **2019** that prepares and outputs `phpinfo()` for my [OpenSource Hosting-Panel "fruithost"](https://github.com/fruithost/).

Here I had found a way to output the `phpinfo()` with the **scope of a previously specified directory**, since a hosting user can also create a `php.ini` in subdirectories.

The special thing about the method was that the whole thing is executed directly via the web server and `PHP-FPM` and thus exclusively uses the `phpinfo();` of a previously specified directory.

Unfortunately for me, I had lost the part at that time due to git stashing, my efforts to recover the file (here I have already exhausted all conceivable possibilities) were in vain.

Now I want to start the whole topic anew and look again for the possibility to implement my intention.

**Problem with the story:**

I can't just print `phpinfo()`, because here the configuration is printed, which runs over a completely different context. As you know, there is no `phpinfo('/path/to/php.ini')` method.

Using the PHP CLI via `php -i -c /destination/path/` does not work here, because the whole thing is executed by php-cli with a different context and also the output does not happen in HTML. In particular, other PHP modules that do not represent the configuration of PHP-FPM are loaded here.

**Desired behavior:**

On the screenshot you can see what is needed:
At the very top right, a domain can be selected. For example `example.com` or `sample.net`. The domains are located in the following path:

> /var/fruithost/`<username>`/`<domain>`/

If the user selects a domain in the upper right corner (example `sample.net`), `phpinfo()` uses the directory `/var/fruithost/<username>/sample.net/`, because a `php.ini` could be located here.

This base is then used to control the output of `phpinfo()`.

**What are the ideas and approaches?**

For those interested: I had uploaded a screenshot back when I finished the 2019 part, this is what the result looked like:
[image: Preview]

Comment: Only thing I can really see working without jumping through too many hoops here, would be to create a temporary PHP script file in the target location, and to capture the output of that then. Random, cryptic name (but still checking for collision with any potential user files, before you create it); perhaps even limiting any output to your own localhost being the requesting client (so as to not expose any sensitive info, should anyone ever be able to "guess" such a file name, or find it via an enabled directory listing.)

Comment: Although any such scripts laying around might "disturb" user scripts; imagine I am reading the full content of a directory in any of my scripts, to process all the found files in some way - then I'd probably would not want any of your phpinfo script files to slide into that. (But setting up file system access, so that those files would be hidden from the actual account users, but still have them run with _their_ PHP configuration, will likely not be possible, I suppose.)

Comment: I have also thought about the idea of temporary PHP files. But here there is a specific limitation: accessibility.

The file must then be called via a URL that is available for reading / calling. 

Unfortunately, this idea falls out, because protected directories are also used here.

I had already created the possibility in 2019 and therefore know that my plan works. I can't remember which approach I took here though, that's the biggest problem.

And I'm annoyed that the script I had worked out got lost.

Comment: *"a hosting user can also create a php.ini in subdirectories"* You mean [.user.ini files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: Did you consider parsing the .user.ini file to get the specific settings?

Comment: A raw parsing of ini-files are not a great method, its only parsing the specific file, not the nested configuration of all in the system included configurations. Thats not a solution!

Comment: You can create a temporary script in the wwwroot directory of the website in question, then request the script via CURL. and delete it afterwards. A similar approach is used by a tool called PHP manager for IIS. I don't know if it is worth posting as answer but this is a workable approach in your case. It'll also work in sub-directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a other solution, with better way to call `PHP-FPM` directly:

```
<?php
    # Executement-Path
    $path   = '/var/fruithost/users/admin/' . $this->domain . '/';
    
    # PHP-fpm
    $socket = '/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock';
    
    # Create temporarely phpinfo();
    $tmp    = '.~fh.tmp.info.php';
    file_put_contents(sprintf('%s%s', $path, $tmp), '<?php phpinfo(); ?>');
    
    $args = '';
    foreach([
        'SCRIPTS_DIR'       => $tmp,
        'HOME'              => $path,
        'PWD'               => $path,
        'DOCUMENT_ROOT'     => $path,
        'SCRIPT_FILENAME'   => sprintf('%s%s', $path, $tmp),
        'REQUEST_METHOD'    => 'GET'
    ] AS $name => $value) {
        $args .= sprintf('%s=%s \\%s', $name, $value, PHP_EOL);
    }
    
    $command    = sprintf('%scgi-fcgi -bind -connect "%s" 2>&1', $args, $socket);
    $result     = shell_exec($command);
    @unlink(sprintf('%s%s', $path, $tmp));
    
    print_r($result);
?>
```

I think my previous version from 2019 has no used temporare files, but its another (ugly) way here.